# Baggage transfer in Beijing?

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer, beijing

I am confused as to how to ensure my baggage is checked through while in international transit, but with two bookings.

My office booked me a return flight from South Africa (where I am) to Beijing. However, I am traveling immediately to Philippines (prior to the event) in the interim on a flight I booked privately. My initial arrival in Beijing and departure to Manila is on the 19th (and in the same terminal), but single-entry visa for China is only for the 30th.

How do I ensure my bags go through? Must I go through immigration without a visa to collect my bags? Tell the airline before I leave to transfer? Is there a way to collect bags in transit?

Comment: So you have JNB-PEK-JNB and PEK-MNL-PEK? Different airlines? Which ones?

Comment: User has not returned to clarify questions. Putting on hold.